# Convert string read from a local mdx file to a window.document object

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, jsdom, mdxjs

I have a next.js project using `mdx-bundler'`

Is there a way to convert string read from a local mdx file to a `window.document` object so I can use `querySelector` to query dom elements?

for example, I have a mdx file like this:

```
## h2
dfdfd
### h3
#### h4
```

Now I can read this string `"## h2 dfdfd ### h3 #### h4"` from my code. Is there a way to convert this string into something that can be feed into `new JSDOM()` so I can use `window.document.querySelector` on it to get `h2`, `h3` and `h4` elements from the mdx?